# How to share data between ViewModel class and ICommand classes using MVVM in WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am writing a WPF application and trying to teach myself the MVVM pattern.  I am using the instructions located on Samuel Jack's site:
http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/09/hooking-up-commands-to-events-in-wpf.html

I have bound my commands to the buttons and hooked everything up.  The command classes are inner classes of the ViewModel class, which implement ICommand.  The complex part is when the commands that run from my buttons need to access data on my view.  Since C# inner classes can not access members of the outer class, I find myself having to declare public static variables in the ViewModel calss just to get data over to the inner classes.  This seems to be a hackish and inelegant solution.  Does anyone have a better way to do this?

My ViewModel code:

```
public class ApplicationViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<App> AppCollection { get; set; }
    static string searchString;
    static string emailString;
    public App SelectedApp { get; set; }
    public string AppToSearch
    {
        get
        {
            return searchString;
        }
        set
        {
            searchString = value;
        }
    }
    public string AppToRequest
    {
        get
        {
            get emailString;
        }
        set
        {
            // set static email String here
        }
    }
    private SearchButtonCommand searchButtonCmd;
    private ClearButtonCommand clearButtonCmd;
    private EmailButtonCommand emailButtonCmd;

    public ApplicationViewModel()
    {
        this.AppCollection = ApplicationsModel.Current;
    }

    public ICommand SearchButtonPressed
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.searchButtonCmd == null)
            {
                this.searchButtonCmd = new SearchButtonCommand();
            }
            return this.searchButtonCmd;
        }
    }

    public ICommand ClearButtonPressed
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.clearButtonCmd == null)
            {
                this.clearButtonCmd = new ClearButtonCommand();
            }
            return this.clearButtonCmd;
        }
    }

    public ICommand EmailButtonPressed
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.emailButtonCmd == null)
            {
                this.emailButtonCmd = new EmailButtonCommand();
            }
            return this.emailButtonCmd;
        }
    }

    private class SearchButtonCommand : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            string searchkey = ApplicationViewModel.searchString;
            ApplicationsModel.Current.Search(searchkey);
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private class ClearButtonCommand : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            ApplicationsModel.Current.ClearSearch();
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private class EmailButtonCommand : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            string targetEmail = ApplicationViewModel.emailString;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

My XAML:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:ApplicationViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Grid.Row="0" Height="84" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,5,5,5" Name="imgLogo" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="600" Source="C:\Images\bannerlong.png" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Search for Application">
            <Label.Foreground>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="LightCyan" />
            </Label.Foreground>
        </Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" Width="500" Text="{Binding AppToSearch}" />
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="100" Height="20" Margin="3" Background="LightCyan" Content="Search" vm:ButtonBehaviour.SearchCommand="{Binding SearchButtonPressed}" />
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="100" Height="20" Margin="3" Background="LightCyan" Content="Clear Search" vm:ButtonBehaviour.ClearCommand="{Binding ClearButtonPressed}"/>
    </Grid>
    <ListView Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AppCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedApp}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Application Name" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Application Description" Width="800" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Application Owner" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Owner}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <Button Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Height="30" Margin="3" Background="LightCyan" Content="Request Application" vm:ButtonBehaviour.EmailCommand="{Binding EmailButtonPressed}" />
</Grid>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `RelayCommand` class that allows you to invoke delegates. With this approach, you don't need to declare a class for each Command.

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    #region Miembros

    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        }

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Miembros de ICommand

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then your ViewModel class will be something like:

```
public class ApplicationViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<App> AppCollection { get; set; }
    private string searchString;
    private string emailString;
    public App SelectedApp { get; set; }
    public string AppToSearch
    {
        get
        {
            return searchString;
        }
        set
        {
            searchString = value;
        }
    }
    public string AppToRequest
    {
        get
        {
            return emailString;
        }
        set { emailString = value; }
    }

    private ICommand searchButtonCmd;
    private ICommand clearButtonCmd;
    private ICommand emailButtonCmd;

    public ApplicationViewModel()
    {
        this.AppCollection = ApplicationsModel.Current;
    }

    public ICommand SearchButtonPressed
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.searchButtonCmd == null)
            {
                this.searchButtonCmd = new RelayCommand(SearchButtonPressedExecute, c=>CanSearch);
            }
            return this.searchButtonCmd;
        }
    }

    private void SearchButtonPressedExecute(object parameter)
    {
        ApplicationsModel.Current.Search(searchString);
    }

    public bool CanSearch
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    // TODO: You can figure out the rest of the code
}
```

Don't forget update your Button's XAML like:

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="100" Height="20" Margin="3" Background="LightCyan" Content="Search" Command="{Binding SearchButtonPressed}" />
```

And the same for the other buttons.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can have a delegate or event in your viewmodel that your command classes use to get the data

.. or you can pass data from the view to the command via command parameter.

```
Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, Element=listBox}" />
```